# Is innodb_log_file_size not relevant if you are not using transactions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand the variables:

```
innodb_log_file_size
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit
```

As I understand the `innodb_log_file_size` is for undo and redo purposes for when cancelling a transaction and for when server crashes. Does this mean that I can kind of ignore this if I don't plan on writing queries of the form:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + 100 WHERE account_id = 98;
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance - 100 WHERE account_id = 42;
COMMIT;
```

I also heard somewhere that

> Every INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE is a transaction if autocommit=1.

What does this mean?

If I do zero transactions, will I gain any performance by setting `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0`? Since I won't need to sync after every transaction commit. But again I heard on youtube that if autocommit=1, then every insert, update, and delete "is a transaction".

I am confused.

Comment: This is better suited to the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com). InnoDB keeps a journal of everything, and individual statements not inside an explicit transaction are treated as if they were wrapped in a transaction that's committed (or auto-committed) unless they're killed before they finish. You absolutely end up using the MVCC engine if you make any alterations to your data whatsoever.

Comment: [Cross-posted to dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166903/11651).